# Build a data structure for saving students

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I need help with a question from my homework :

Build a data structure for saving students: Each student has a name, id and an
an array of grades. Create a function that receives such data structure as first
parameter, a grade as the second one, and find all the grades that higher then
that grade.

my data structure :

```json
var students = [
  { 
    name: "Student 1",
    id : '258741',
    grades: [ 65, 61, 67, 70 ]
  },
  { 
    name: "Student 2",
    id : '369852',
    grades: [ 50, 51, 53, 90 ]
  },
  { 
    name: "Student 3",
    id : '654321',
    grades: [ 35, 20, 40, 60 ]
  }
];
```

how  I write a function that compares each number(from the array number) from each student and gets only a high number than some value like 65?

please don't joke at me I'm new in this area!
thank you!!

Comment: Please include your own attempt to solve this problem

Comment: Not "joking" on you, but you need to show your attempts. Stackoverflow isn't here to do your homework for you. It's to help you solve a problem when you get stuck making your own attempts. You haven't demonstrated that you've made any attempt of your own yet, so you're not really "stuck." You're just asking for the answers.

Comment: Put your attempts in your question, not in your comments.

Comment: `code`  
chk_grd = 64
function checkGrade(students,chk_grd){
    for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        let numbers = students[i].grades;
        if (numbers[i].grades > chk_grd) {
            console.log(numbers[i])   
        }
    }
    
}
checkGrade(students,chk_grd)

Comment: i'm add my attempt

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to print the grades of each student which are greater than 64:

```js
var students = [{
    name: "Student 1",
    id: '258741',
    grades: [65, 61, 67, 70]
  },
  {
    name: "Student 2",
    id: '369852',
    grades: [50, 51, 53, 90]
  },
  {
    name: "Student 3",
    id: '654321',
    grades: [35, 20, 40, 60]
  }
];

let chk_grd = 64

function checkGrade(students, chk_grd) {
  for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {//for each student
    let numbers = students[i].grades;
    numbers.map((num) => num > chk_grd ? console.log(num) : null)//for each grade of each student
  }
}

checkGrade(students, chk_grd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function checkGrade(students,chk_grd){ 
        for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) { 
           let numbers = students[i].grades; 
           for(let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
              if (numbers[j] > chk_grd) {
                 console.log(numbers[j]) 
              } 
           }
        }
     }
     
    //Test
    var students = [
      { 
        name: "Student 1",
        id : '258741',
        grades: [ 65, 61, 67, 70 ]
      },
      { 
        name: "Student 2",
        id : '369852',
        grades: [ 50, 51, 53, 90 ]
      },
      { 
        name: "Student 3",
        id : '654321',
        grades: [ 35, 20, 40, 60 ]
      }
    ];
    checkGrade(students, 64);
```

You has to compare grades one by one.